# Can I get each value based on key from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    foo: bar,
    bar: foo,
  },
  {
    foo: bar,
    bar: baz,
  },
  {
    foo: bar,
    bar: foo,
  },
]
```

And I wish to get out an array that looks like this:

```
[foo, baz, foo]
```

Is this possible with pure JS or underscore? I only need to support modern browsers.

Comment: So loop through the Array, read the object, push to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UnderscoreJS has `_.pluck()`

```
_.pluck(yourArray,'bar') 
 => [foo,baz,foo]
```

From [UnderscoreJS docs for _.pluck()](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck):

> ```
> _.pluck(list, propertyName)
> ```
>
> A convenient version of what is perhaps the most common use-case
>   for map: extracting a list of property values.
>
> ```
> var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
> _.pluck(stooges, 'name');
>  => ["moe", "larry", "curly"]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

With ES5 (pure JS):

```
var result = thatArray.map(function (x) { return x.bar; });
```

or with underscore:

```
var result = _.map(thatArray, function (x) { return x.bar; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var result = arr.map(function(obj){
   return obj.bar;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pure JS:** This code will work in non strict mode. It's probably not the most efficient way. But, I think it's quite simple.

```
var A = [
  {
    foo: "bar",
    bar: "foo",
  },
  {
    foo: "bar",
    bar: "baz",
  },
  {
    foo: "bar",
    bar: "foo",
  },
]
var key = "bar";
var length = A.length;
var B = [];
for(var i = 0; i < length; ++i){
  if(A[i][key]){
    B[B.length] = A[i][key];
  }
}
console.log(B);
```